# Gnome apps display under gnome search and window overview

Tags: gnome, display, gnome-shell, gui

Here is an example [image: example]

I have tried removing all addons, themes, tweaks and resetting the desktop to default. I have tried to search for the issue but either can't find a duplicate or I am not using the exact search terms to uncover duplicate issues. This is ubuntu 21.04 and Gnome 3.38.4

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you reset all setting? `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/`. Does it occur as soon as you press the Super key to go into the overview, or only after specific actions?